# Rename the "offers remote" perk to "offers telecommuting", and add a separate option for filtering jobs that are full-time remote

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When looking for remote work, I want to be able to search for jobs that are remote exclusive, as opposed to jobs that merely offer a telecommute option but still require their workers to be physically located near the office.